# How to access page of a multipage pdf file in Gimp?

Tags: gimp

When I open a multipage pdf file, gimp lets me select the pages I want to import.  After opening the file, the first page selected appears in a file window.  How do I access the other pages?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each page is loaded as a layer. To see a page you have to make the layers above it invisible, this is done by clicking the eye icon on the left of the layer thumbnails in the Layers list.

Shift-click on the icon of a Layer toggles the visibility of all other layers, so this is a very quick way to make it visible.

If you need to put all the pages side by side, there are scripts for this, for instance `ofn-layer-tiles` that you will find [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/).

Comment: Thanks.  Alternative solution:  it turns out that in the page selection dialog window, you can specify 'images' instead of the default which is 'layers'.  Then each pages opens in a separate window.